# mysql - Is it a good practice to have a lot of events?

Tags: mysql, datetime, scheduled-tasks

I have a table **tblMatch** :

```
+---------+---------------------+------------------+-----------+ 
|  ID     |      start_date     |     end_date     |  status   | 
+---------+---------------------+------------------+-----------+ 
|  1      |   2017-12-09 03:23  | 2017-12-10 03:23 |      1    | 
+---------+---------------------+------------------+-----------+ 
| ...     |         ...         |       ...        |      1    | 
+---------+---------------------+------------------+-----------+ 
| 1000000 |   2017-12-22 15:12  | 2017-12-30 15:12 |      1    | 
+---------+---------------------+------------------+-----------+
```

When I insert a row, I create one event too.
Event will change status to 0 if the match is ended.

```
CREATE EVENT test_event_increment_number
ON SCHEDULE AT end_date
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
DO
   UPDATE tblMatch SET status = 0 WHERE ID = increment_number;
```

If **tblMatch** has 100 million matches :
Does it effect server performance?
Is it bad or good idea to create a lot of events?

Answer (score 4):

Create just 1 event that runs daily and closes the matches expiring that day.

```
CREATE EVENT test_event
ON SCHEDULE AT 1 every day
STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
DO
   UPDATE tblMatch SET status = 0 WHERE end_date = CURRENT_DATE;
```

UPDATE

If you want to time your events at a minute level, then either change the frequency of your event to minute level and use minute level when determining if a match needs closing, or completely drop the status field and just use the `end_date` field's value compared to `now()` to determine if the event is closed. The latter is a better way.

Comment: if the event start at 3 pm does the match will end at 3 pm too?

Comment: Then change the event to run at every hour and make sure that it closes every event down in that our.

Comment: If the match start at 3 pm but the event runs at 3:45 pm so the match will not end.

Comment: So is it good for performance that compare end_date with now() for million of rows?

Comment: I can't possibly answer your last comment. Use appropriate indexes to speed queries up.

Comment: Note that `WHERE end_date = CURRENT_DATE` will unlikly match, because CURRENT_DATE will be casted to timestamp/datetime with `00:00:00` as time part. http://rextester.com/JAT99783

Comment: @PaulSpiegel the question has been changed, see the updated section of my answer.

Comment: Well - I vote for "completely drop the status field".

Comment: @PaulSpiegel : If I query with : SELECT * FROM tblMatch WHERE end_date > CURRENT_DATE;   does it fast or not with increasing the row of table?

Answer (score 1):

I Create 25 events is different time.  After a while, the database takes all the resources, and reboots.

```
   CREATE EVENT `auction_event_46709`
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2017-12-07 10:23:03'
   ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
   DO CALL auction_update_price(46709)
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `auction_update_price`( IN p_id INT )
BEGIN
 DECLARE cur_price INT;
 DECLARE stp_price INT;
 DECLARE st_price INT;
 DECLARE str_price INT;
 SELECT current_price, step_price, stop_price, start_price INTO cur_price, stp_price, st_price, str_price FROM product_to_auction WHERE product_id = p_id;
 IF( cur_price - stp_price > st_price ) THEN
   UPDATE product_to_auction SET current_price = current_price - step_price WHERE current_price > stop_price AND product_id = p_id;
 ELSE
    UPDATE product_to_auction SET current_price = str_price WHERE product_id = p_id;
 END IF;
END
```

How to Fix?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use events at all for this sort of operation. Certainly don't use many events for it. Instead, use a query (or view) that takes your `end_date` into account and determines your `status` value dynamically based on date. For example, to retrieve a particular item by `id`, do this.

```
 SELECT id, start_date, end_date
        CASE WHEN end_date <= CURDATE() THEN 0  ELSE status END AS status
   FROM tblMatch
  WHERE id = something
```

This query returns the row from the table, along with the `status` value based on the moment you run the query. (I set it up so items with `status` = 0 are always marked as expired never mind the current time.)

If you want all the items with status 1 (meaning non expired) do this:

```
 SELECT id, start_date, end_date, 1 AS status
   FROM tblMatch
  WHERE end_date < CURDATE ()
    AND status = 1
```

If you MUST use an event, you can run it once a day, sometime after midnight to reset the `status` columns of all expiring rows to 0, with a query like this.

```
  UPDATE tblMatch SET status = 0 WHERE status = 1 AND end_date < CURDATE();
```

(I prefer to run daily update queries shortly after 03:00 local time. Why? I'm located in the USA, and our daylight saving time switchover is done, twice a year, at 02:00 local time. Doing daily updates after 03:00 ensures they'll still work properly on switchover days. )

For these queries to be efficient, you need a compound index on `(status, end_date)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment.